# Está mal crear un tema en Meta solo por que Soapbox lo requiere?

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2020

No tengo motivos, ni razones fuera de lo que es la curiosidad de lo de Winter Bash.
No siento que sea necesario hacerlo, pero realmente creo que no podría crear un tema, 
solo por que un sombrero me lo solicita.

Pero aún así, la curiosidad es mayor, el impulso de idiotez también.

Aprovecho de mandar saludos, en especial a la gente que se une y participa del Chat **"Stack Overflow en español"**

No me siento nada orgulloso de hacer esto, pero como dije...
me gana la curiosidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya que publicas una pregunta, intenta que sea útil para la comunidad en general :P

Comment: A eso me refiero, la medalla o sombrero, de por sí no motiva a hacerlo de ese modo necesariamente. Y como mencioné, no tengo motivos para hacer una del estilo aún.

Comment: De hecho con esta pregunta has hecho una meta metapregunta, lo que en cierta medida ya la hace interesante jaja

Comment: Es por eso que me mata de curiosidad jaja

Comment: A los que están haciendo eso les va a tocar hacer de diablo en la pastorela y cantar villancicos a capela todo el mes de diciembre.

Comment: Pues tendré que acompañarlos jajaja

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entiendo que una recompensa como un sombrero o una medalla son para fomentar algún tipo de comportamiento o acción.

Desde luego StackOverflow con esta recompensa en forma de sombrero ha conseguido que hagas tu primera pregunta en meta.

A lo mejor a partir de ahora que ya has hecho una pregunta, te animes a hacer más, esta vez más centradas en la temática de el sitio.

Así que no veo mal que hagas esa pregunta, no es culpa tuya querer ganar una recompensa y creo que está cumpliendo su función ya que has dado el paso de hacer tu pregunta en meta.

Comment: Claro, de cierto modo, estos "motivadores" me animan a realizar ciertas acciones solo por obtener dicha medalla/sobrero. Muchas de ellas pueden ser contraproducentes perse, como unirme a comunidades que jamás usaré, o esta misma, crear una pregunta sin fundamento más que el "esta medalla me dijo que lo hiciera"

Answer (score 2):

> Está mal crear un tema en Meta solo por que Soapbox lo requiere?

No, no lo considero así.

La pregunta a crear debería ser el último recurso a usar - luego de buscar (*no solo en los sitios de Stack Exchange*), probar y en general, sin tener otro recurso de ayuda.